# javafx fullscreen window scaling

Tags: javafx, fullscreen, positioning

So i am making a cardgame using javafx and MVP.
in my startscreen i added an option where the user can choose to put the window in fullscreen or windowed.

The problem i'm having is that when you choose the fullscreen mode the objects on the screen are not adjusting to a higher window size.

windowed mode:
https://gyazo.com/26e7a258f945fb5b9c7b16e925b4e2a8

fullscreen mode:
http://prnt.sc/acp6nl

like you can see on fullscreen mode there is more room on the bottom right.

code of startpresenter(it refers to gameview)

```
            Gameview gameview = new Gameview();
            Startview startview = new Startview();
            Gamepresenter presenter3 = new Gamepresenter(model, gameview);
            view.getScene().setRoot(gameview);
            gameview.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            gameview.getScene().getWindow().centerOnScreen();
            Stage stage = (Stage )gameview.getScene().getWindow();



            if (view.getFullscreen().isSelected() ) {
                stage.setFullScreen(true);
            }`
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something with alignment? Can you give us the code of the gameview?